# Serilog: difference between {..} and {@..}

Tags: .net, serilog

Given this code:

```
var d1 = new { x = 5, y = 88 };
Log.Logger.Information("{d1}", d1);
Log.Logger.Information("{@d1}", d1);
```

How will the object in d1 be logged differently in the two Log.Logger.Information(...) lines?
In other words, what is the effect of adding the @ in between the {  } ?

I read https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data under the heading "Preserving Object Structure", but that didn't make sense to me.

Comment: There's actually `{..}` (default), `{$..}` (stringify), and `{@..}` (destructure). Is [this](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/60e8120a12abee4db942d2ff03b123341fab1fff/src/Serilog/Parsing/Destructuring.cs) *maybe* of more help?

Comment: This didn't clear it up for me. Both "default" and "destructure" seem to store objects as structured objects, rather than strings. I appreciate there is a difference, but can't see it.

Comment: Conveniently, someone just wrote a great Pluralsight course explaining this, too: http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/modern-structured-logging-serilog-seq

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`{d1}` converts unrecognized types like the anonymous one here into `string`s for logging, i.e. using `ToString()`. So your log event in the first example will end up with a property like (here in JSON):

```
{
  "d1": "{ x = 5, y = 88 }"
}
```

Using `{@d1}` will cause the parameter to be serialized as structured data:

```
{
  "d1":
  {
    "x": 5,
    "y": 88
  }
}
```

Where appropriate, the second example is much more useful for manipulation/analysis.

The reason for this "opt-in" requirement is that most types in .NET programs convert nicely into strings, but *aren't* cleanly/meaningfully serializable. By opting in to serialization with `@` you're saying: "I know what I'm doing, serialize this object!" :)

Comment: What if the object has a public property which is of type List<int> ? I see that Serilog is destructuring the object and lists all the properties which are double and integer but leaves off this particular property which is of type List.

Comment: @NotAgain is it possible the list is a public field, rather than a property? Serilog ignores fields, so that's one possibility. If not - could you post your code in a new question? Cheers!

Comment: Spot on. It is a field and not a property. My mistake.